Is this probability Misconception
If you draw two cards, what is probability that second card is a queen?

As you know this is a simple problem One can easily solve by taking cases
The probability that the second card is a queen can be calculated as:
$$P(\text{second card is queen}) = \frac{48}{52} \times \frac{4}{51} + \frac{4}{52} \times \frac{3}{51} = \frac{1}{13}$$
If you try to calculate the probability using combinations, you might think of it as:
$$\text{Probability} = \frac{\left(\binom{48}{1} \times \binom{4}{1}\right) + \left(\binom{4}{1} \times \binom{3}{1}\right)}{\binom{52}{2}}$$
Simplifying this expression:
$$\frac{(48 \times 4 + 4 \times 3)}{\frac{52 \times 51}{2}} = \frac{51 \times 4 \times 2}{51 \times 52}$$
This correct seeming method yields a different result. Why does this occur?
Why does the method using combinations fail to give the correct probability? What is causing the discrepancy?
If we can't use combinations in this question, then how we can figure out when we can use combination?

I don't understand the second method.  The final answer, $\frac 8{52}$ is much too high.  After all, each rank must yield the same result and the total would sum to greater than $1$.  it is, of course, suggestive that that answer is exactly twice the correct one.

@Peter This might be posted as an answer.

@lulu Might be because of some combinations order problem? Not sure, though.

That's usually the culprit when you are off by a factor of $2$, and that's the claim made by @Peter in the posted solution.

You do not need any calculation at all. The situation does not distinguish between ant two cards, so the probability must be 1/13.

The error is that in the numerator , you count the possibilities considering the order , in the denominator the possibilities not considering the order. Therefore , you are off by a factor $2$
